# Multiple Testing in A Logistic Regression Model?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statsmodels

We want to test if an exam is particularly hard for students in certain racial group(s) to pass (pass = 1, fail = 0). The independent variables include (per row per student using student ID as a primary key):

1. Students’ class attendance rate
2. Number of exercise completed
3. Average exercise scores
4. Number of practice exams
5. % of practice exam passed
6. Student race (including Asian, Black, Hispanic, American Indian and Alaska Native,
   Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander)

A logistic regression (glm() in R) will be used to predict whether a student will pass or fail the exam.

Questions:

- Student race will be used as a dummy variable, is there a way to conduct multiple testing while controlling for variables listed above in a logistic regression? (like comparing asian to black, asian to white, asian to hispanic, etc, same for other race groups)
- What metrics to use to decide if students' race statistically significant affect students' probability of passing the exam? I was tempted to use p-value of race variable but understand researchers use effect size and confidence intervals of that variable. What is the best approach here?
- We care about students who are predicted (using threshold of 0.5) to pass the exam, but actually failed it (that is, FALSE POSITIVES).  Is there any metric that we can use to  compare FALSE POSITIVE by race group after controlling for race variable?

Comment: If you have a score for the exams, you might be better off modelling the score directly than only pass/fail

Comment: We do not actual scores. The outcome variable only has pass or fail values.